# How to overwrite TextChannel permissions

Tags: node.js, discord, user-permissions, discord.js

I have code a Discord Bot, with Node.js, and I want, with the code of my bot, assign a permission for a player

For explain a little more details, I try to create the board game "Werewolves", for playing with my friend on Discord. I develloped this bot (with node.js ; I'm a beginner), allowing, when I enter a command on Discord, to send a message to a player for saying his role in the game.

But I'm blocking in something now : for example for players who are "Werewolves", I want to give her an access to a channel, so that they can talk together, and the others players can't view the messages (I can make that with "roles", but when somebody check the role of an another player, he can view his role ; eand I don't think there is something to don't see roles of a player)

I have check the library discord.js, and I view two solutions ; but I can't get both to work !
The first : (the constant "lg" is for Werewolves ; loup-garou in french ^^)

```
 .then(function(member) {
     let lg = new Discord.Permissions(member, 0x00000400)
 })
```

The second "solution" :

```
.overwritePermissions(guild.member {
    'VIEW_CHANNEL': true 
    'SEND_MESSAGES': true 
    'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY': true
})
```

I repeat, but I have already explained above; I'm trying to get, the fact that the player has a new "role" (but that is not a role I want to add to him), to assign him the permissions for he can see a special channel (Werewolf-channel if he's a werewolf in the game), and he can send a message on that same channel

Here is a screen (https://prnt.sc/k5qvvb): with the arrow, it is the place where the user should have his name (here for example it's my account ^^), and in yellow the permissions he should have (putting others in "false" is obviously not required)

I get no error, the console doesn't show anything abnormal... But the bot doesn't do what I want ^^

Thanks for your help :)
Oxzir

PS : i'm french, so sorry if my english isn't sooo good ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second try is correct, but you're passing `guild.member` as the user, but that's not a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) (it's [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)). Because, that property doesn't exists.

Try passing a [`UserResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/UserResolvable) type object: [`<Message>.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author), [`<Message>.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member).

```js
message.guild.channels.find('name', 'loups-garous')
.overwritePermissions(UserResolvable, { // Pass 'UserResolvable' type thing as described in Wiki!
  VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
  SEND_MESSAGES: true,
  READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true,
  ATTACH_FILES: false
});
```

Comment: Hello ^^

Thanks you for your answer ! But I've a little error with this : [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/454297485985316875/467444949437382656/erreur_channel_function.PNG)

A friend looked at this error, and said I've to make that : [link](https://hastebin.com/zunahukaqa.js)
(the beginning is a little different compared to your)
But I've a different error : [link](https://hastebin.com/erawudacew.coffeescript)

Comment: Sorry, I wrote a really stupid thing without testing it '-_-. Your second try is right, I edited the answer, try now ;)

Comment: I was not at home this week-end, also sorry I can't answer you before :/
I have an error with this code... That's my bot index : [link](https://hastebin.com/devipafeje.cs) (your code is form lign 30 to 40 ^^ ), and I've tested, with `message.member.channels.find()` but that don't work ([link](https://hastebin.com/vuboxumacu.bash) :/ )

Comment: Next I've tested with `message.guild.channels.find()`, and that don't make the same error ! But it's still a mistake x) : [link](https://hastebin.com/texuliceca.css), and I can test with user_id, or tolg.id (a friend said that can work) ; the both don't work :(
Now I understand nothing xD

Do you think it can work in the end ?

Comment: The first didn't work because `message.member.channels` does not exist. 
The second one doesn't work because the user_id is not a UserResolvable, but I can't help you if you don't post your code. Please post your code (the one that generates the second error)

Comment: Here is my code : [link](https://hastebin.com/qacazojova.cs)
The problem is from lign 30 to 40 ; the rest is all the same (to assign "role" by dm to a player ; and that's work). Thank you for all you have already make ^^

Comment: You have to replace `"user_id"` with the id of the user you want to give/deny permissions to.

Comment: Thanks! And... Is there something for use the mention of the user in the command to replace user_id?

Comment: Sorry I've answer but I haven't test :/ There is the same error... To replace user_id, i've use "@Oxzir#4751" or "Oxzir#4751", but that don't work :(

Comment: That's not the [user id](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=id): you can get the id from msg.author.id and so on with every User object. If you toggle the developer mode in Discord you can right-click users and copy their id.

Comment: I've tested and that make the same "User" and "Role" error :(     Sorry if I am boring with my problem :/

Comment: Yes sure ^^ [link](https://hastebin.com/resojujogo.cs) The user_id is my id

Comment: I've added an example of what I mean. Just modify that

Comment: Great! Can you accept the answer so that it doesn't appear as an unanswered question?

Comment: I juste have view on the wiki with your code the command, and I have replace the id by `message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]))` ; for the id of the user I had mentionned : and that works too !!! :D