# How to update user permission discord js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So, I want to update a permission for some users.
First, I tried to create a text channel and overwrite a user Permission. Then I do a for loop to update the permission, but I dont know how. 
Things I've tried to update the permission :

```
channel.overwritePermissions({
    permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            id: guild.id,
            deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        },
        {
            id: playerData[i],
            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        },
    ],
});
//it said channel not defined?
```

```
message.guild.channels.cache.find('werewolves').overwritePermissions({
        permissionOverwrites: [
            {
            id: playerData[i],
            allow:['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            }
        ]
    })
//it said : fn is not a function
```

I've I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324058/how-to-overwrite-textchannel-permissions) solution and read the [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#replacing-overwrites), but the instruction isn't clear.

PS : The permission update must be a loop because the number of users who get the permission always changing.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using? What version of node are you running?

Comment: I am using discord.js version 12.1.1 and node.js version 12.16.1

Answer (score 1):

#### Regarding first codeblock

`channel` is not defined, because it's not defined. You cannot use variables without defining them, that's how JavaScript works. To solve it, you would have to define it using for example `const channel = ...`, or access it from other variables you have, just like you are trying to use `find` in your second codeblock - you access it from `message`, as you're most likely in the message event.

#### Regarding second codeblock

This is not a proper way to use `find`, neither in old - removed in your version - way, nor the new way. The old way was to do `find(property, value)`, to which you wouldn't provide a value (`'werewolves'` would be treated as property you're trying to search by). New way you have to use, allows way more flexibility by requiring to pass it a function, just like in the [example](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) for the method. Since what you passed was a string and not a function, internal code throws an error `fn is not a function`.

For your example above, correct way to use that find would be

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'werewolves');
```

Additionally, note that ideally you shouldn't try to call any methods on that directly, as in case when no channel with that name would be found, your code will throw an error. Snippet below should avoid that possibility.

```js
const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'werewolves');
if (channel) channel.overwritePermissions(...)
```