# discord.js setting permission on channel to "/" (neutral)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am looking to set user permissions on a text channel to neutral/null/"/" but `overwritePermissions()` seems to only use allow and deny currently, a [past post I saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324058/how-to-overwrite-textchannel-permissions) showed setting the value to null but allow/deny seems to prevent that.

I am setting permissions on a text channel like this:

```js
member.guild.channels.cache.array().forEach((channel) => {
 channel.overwritePermissions([
  {
   id: member,
   deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
  },
 ]);
});
```

and would like to effectively undo this action, changing the ['VIEW_CHANNEL'] permission to allow overrides other permissions in the server and does not work for my case.

[`overwritePermissions()` documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions)

Comment: I think you're looking for [`updateOverwrite()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite)

Comment: Thank you so much, never noticed that tucked in the corner, if you want to submit that as an answer I would be glad to accept it :)

Comment: Alright, sure 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [`Channel#updateOverwrites()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite) which, as well as having a different function to `overwritePermissions()`, also has a different format.

`overwritePermissions` overwrites all the permissions in a channel (as suggested by its name). So even if you only want to change one thing, `overwritePermissions` will bring everything with it. Thankfully, we also have `updateOverwrites`. This method will only change permissions for *one* member/role.

Here's how you could use it:

```js
// as a note, `forEach()` automatically coverts the collection to an array,
// so no need for the `array()` function
member.guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel) => {
 channel.updateOverwrite(member, { // update permissions only for the member
  VIEW_CHANNEL: null, // set view_channel to default
 });
});
```

Comment: It's channel.updateOverwrite (Channel#updateOverwrites()) & (channel.updatePermissions) :p

also thanks for that tip, i didnt know it converted

Comment: Honestly I need some coffee I get those mixed up way too often

Comment: Glad I could help :)