# discord.js Tickets-like bot error - 'TypeError: fn.bind is not a function'

Tags: discord.js

I'm currently in the process of trying to make a tickets-like system and while running my code, I got the following error:
`TypeError: fn.bind is not a function`

Is something wrong with my code? Thanks!

```
command(client, 'channel', (message, user) => {
    user = message.member;
    user = user.toString();
    if (user.includes("!")) {
        user = user.split("!")[1].split(">")[0];
    } else {
        user = user.split("@")[1].split(">")[0];
    }
    let name = client.users.cache.get(user).username
    message.channel.send(name)
    console.log(`${message.author.name} has created a new ticket.`)
    message.guild.channels
    .create(`Channel-${name}`, {
        type: 'text',
    })
    .then((channel) => {
        channel.setParent('776390304848674836').then((settedParent) => { // Zet kanaal in category.

            // Put permissions for everyone
            settedParent.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.cache.find('name', "@everyone"), { "READ_MESSAGES": false });
            settedParent.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.cache.find('name', "@management"), { "VIEW_CHANNEL": true });
            // Put permission by the user that created the ticket
            settedParent.overwritePermissions(message.author, {

                "READ_MESSAGES": true, "SEND_MESSAGES": true,
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: What line is this error referencing?

Comment: I believe it's referring to this line:             settedParent.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.cache.find('name', "@everyone"), { "READ_MESSAGES": false });

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11) You're using outdated `find()` syntax.

Comment: Hi again, I have edited my code to match the code you sent me, although it seems to give me an even bigger error. Have I done something wrong here?

            settedParent.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'everyone'), { "READ_MESSAGES": false })

            settedParent.overwritePermissions(message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Admin'), { "VIEW_CHANNEL": true })

Comment: [replace `overwritePermissions()` with `updateOverwrite()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63900096/discord-js-setting-permission-on-channel-to-neutral/63900333#63900333])

Comment: You're an absolute legend my guy, thank you so so so much! <3

Comment: Glad I could help!