# How to lock and unlock an channel using discord.js v13.4

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I tried a lot of ways to locking a channel to a specific role, this is one of my attempt code:

Locking the channel

```
const Command = require("../structures/Command.js");
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "lock",
    description: "lock the channel that the command is executed",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.ADMINISTRATOR)){
            let role = message.guild.roles.cache(r => r.id === "895151537511362600");
            role.overwritePermissions(UserResolvable, {
    VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
    SEND_MESSAGES: false,
    READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true,
    ATTACH_FILES: false
});            
        } else message.reply(`why do you want to use a mod command when you're not a mod`)

    }
});
```

Unlocking:

```
const Command = require("../structures/Command.js");
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "unlock",
    description: "unlock the channel that the command is executed",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        if (message.author.bot) return;
        if (message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.ADMINISTRATOR)){
            let role = message.guild.roles.cache(r => r.id === "895151537511362600");
            role.overwritePermissions(UserResolvable, {
    VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
    SEND_MESSAGES: true,
    READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true,
    ATTACH_FILES: true
});            
        } else message.reply(`why do you want to use a mod command when you're not a mod`)

    }
});
```

It didn't work, also returned a error say `UserResolvable is not defined`
I also tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324058/how-to-overwrite-textchannel-permissions) and it still didn't work

Comment: The answer to the question you linked states "// Pass 'UserResolvable' type thing as described in Wiki!" In other words, replace it with a user resolvable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/PermissionOverwriteManager?scrollTo=edit) you use [`channel.permissionOverwrites.edit()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/PermissionOverwriteManager?scrollTo=edit)**

So your lock code would look something like this:

```js
message.channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(message.guild.everyone.id, {
    VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
    SEND_MESSAGES: false,
    READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: false,
    ATTACH_FILES: false
});

message.channel.permissionOverwrites.edit("ROLE_ID", {
    VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
    SEND_MESSAGES: true,
    READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true,
    ATTACH_FILES: true
});
```

And then for the unlock command just change the permission values.

Comment: `message.guild.everyone.id`? You mean `message.guild.id` or `message.guild.roles.everyone.id`? (They are both the same anyways)

Answer (score 0):

To lock use like this

```
channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(channel.guild.roles.everyone, {
    SEND_MESSAGES: false
}).catch((e) => { console.error(e) })
```

Comment: I was trying to lock it to a certain role only, not @ everyone role